# Silent push notifications still pop up as normal

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to setup silent push notifications and I'm stuck with this problem. JSON that I send to APNs is:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "test",
    "badge": 0,
    "content-available": 1
  }
}
```

Delegate method is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    var pushData = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable : Any];
    if pushData?["content-available"] as? Int == 1 {
        NSLog("received silent notification")
        completionHandler(.noData)
    } else {
        NSLog("received notification")
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

When backend sends push notification, my app is in background. XCode shows me 'received silent notification', but this notification still pops up as normal. Could you please tell me, what I'm doing is wrong? It probably shouldn't be happening, right?

Project is set up with 'remote notifications' checked in 'background modes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct json payload for silent push notification should look like this

```
{
    "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    };
    // add custom key-value pairs 
}
```